# error when install hg in mac os x 10.9 with python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, mercurial

I'm trying to install hg in my mac.  My OS is 10.9(BD2). I use `easy_install mercurial` or `pip install -U Mercurial`, but all these prints error:

`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

And I can use gcc command in my mac, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like Mercurial, it's often easier and "better" to use the binary distribution. The release for OS X 10.8 can be found [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/mac/binaries/Mercurial-2.6-py2.7-macosx10.8.zip) -- I imagine it will also work on 10.9.  The different releases for different versions of OS X are primarily related to differences in system python. Since 10.8 comes with Python 2.7, which is the newest -- and last -- version of the Python 2.x series, I think it's safe to assume that the Python version won't produce much difficulty here.

The binary distribution has two advantages:

1. you avoid compilation issues, such as ones not related to being able to find the correct headers (suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17480497/2022326)
2. the binary installer will also do all the necessary work involving your path

The "disadvantage" is basically that you have effectively installed a full-fledged Unix utility and not just a python package in your `site-packages` folder.

Another option, albeit much more complicated, is to download the sources and do a full build yourself. It's actually not as hard as it sounds, and you would be able to see exactly where the compile step fails.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you do not have python development headers installed.  If you're on Linux, try installing the dev packages:

```
apt-get install python-dev
apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Otherwise, you can install Mercurial in a virtualenv:

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv
mkdir myenv && cd myenv && virtualenv . && . bin/activate
pip install Mercurial hg-git
```

(only include hg-git in pip install if you need it)

If the virtualenv command in the second line of the Mac instructions is not found in your PATH, then supplying a full path, like this, might work:

```
$  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv .
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. let me look alternative for mac.

Comment: I know how to deal it with Linux, but in OS X it doesn't work.

Comment: I actually tried installing in OS X - Mercurial in virtualenv . and it works . I think you should give my steps for Mac a shot.